# How to write a function that make http request and return the result of the request?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, singleton

The function `getEventId()` is returning `this.eventId`.

If `this.eventId == null`,

1. a function that makes an http request is being called.
2. `this.eventId = resp` (the respons from the request).

   ngOnInit() {
   // the function bellow makes http request.
   this.getCustomerFileByCode().subscribe(data => {
   // get Id from server
   this.eventId = data[0];
   })
   }

   getEventId() {
   if (this.eventId) { //if the server request returned already response
   return of(this.eventId)
   } else {
   getCustomerFileByCode().subscrive(data =>{
   this.eventId = data[0]
   })
   // wait some how to the server response and return the value
   return this.eventId;
   })
   }
   }

   getCustomerFileByCode(): Observable {
   return this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(params), this.options)
   }

How do I return the value from the http request in the function `getEventId()`?

Comment: when you are actually calling `this._customerService.EventId();` line from another service..?

Comment: Hey, I added the missing function so you can understand the code more clearly @ganesh045

Comment: is this `getCustomerFileByCode()` using eventId..?

Comment: No, it's returning the response which includes eventId. @ganesh045

Comment: Create a Subject. Call next() on the subject when the response arrives. Then, anywhere that you're interested in that data, observe the Subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want do some like

```
getEventId(elementId):Observable<any> {
    if (this.eventId) { //if the server request returned already 
        return of(this.eventId)
    } else {
        return this.getCustomerFileByCode(elementId).pipe(
         map(data=>data[0]),
         tap(res => { 
            this.eventId = res;
        })
    }
```

And in ngOnInit

```
    this.getEventId(this.elementId).subscribe(()=> { 
          ...make something more...
          ...don't worry about this.eventId because the "tap" ...
          ...on the observable yet store the value...
    })
```

See that the getEventId return an observable, if "this.eventId" is yet, simply return of, else call to the API, transform the response -using map- and store the value -using tap-. Of course, as all observables you need subscribe to "launch". Well, you can equal teh value in subscribe and don't use "tap". But in general the observables must be declared in a service and subscribe in component, so it's more logical that the variable "belong" to the service.

Comment: eventually I didn't even use the `ngOnInit()` function just used the getEventId() and that is it.
This is exactly what I was looking for! thank you! @Eliseo